# android: access the button drawable in a radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, drawable

just a simple question regarding to radio buttons in Android:

I know I can set a custom button drawable for radio buttons by using this method : RadioButton.setButtonDrawable(Drawable).

However, what if you wanna get access to the button drawable you put in this radio button?

In my application, I am actually trying to make the button part of a radio button animating, I pass a AnimationDrawable object into a radio button, but since I can't figure out how to access this object, there's no way I can call the start() method to get it start animating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep a reference variable of drawable, you can access it from that.

Comment: yea, just figured out the same thing: setButtonDrawable(drawable) then call drawable.start() directly, but this won't work if I set up the radio button in XML.